# Getting the shortest point entry from a List

Tags: java, android

**What i am having**: List of points

```
LinkedList<Point> mList=new LinkedList<Point>();
```

Now i have a new entry which is a `xpoint`.

**What i am trying to do**: I am trying to get the point value from `mList` which is nearest to new entry `xpoint`

**How to achieve this ?**

**What i have tried:**. I tried using `Comparator` as [*here*](https://stackoverflow.com/q/33715706/1083093) but i couldn't get the result i am trying

Comment: Please show us the code using the Comparator that doesn't work and how exactly it fails to work.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/q/33715706/1083093 --------- That is how i tried

Comment: You accepted an answer to that question.  What part of it isn't working?

Comment: That Error in the question i asked got resolved .... But What happens is when i used that flow ...... Distance variable is sorted .... but the Point variables are not sorted ...remains same. - Hope i am clear (Thats why i rephrased to this new question i posted)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No need for sorting and `Comparator`s. Simply iterate over the `List` and keep track of the `Point` nearest the target `Point`:

```
private Point getNearestPoint(List<Point> pointList, Point target) {
    Point nearest = null;
    double shortestDistance = Double.MAX_VALUE;
    double distance = 0;

    for(Point p : pointList) {
        distance = getDistance(p, target);
        if(distance < shortestDistance) {
            shortestDistance = distance;
            nearest = p;
        }
    }

    return nearest;
}

private double getDistance(Point p1, Point p2) {
    return Math.sqrt(Math.pow(p1.x - p2.x, 2) + Math.pow(p1.y - p2.y, 2));
}
```